# Tensorflow: My loss function produces huge number

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying image inpainting using a NN with weights pretrained using denoising autoencoders. All according to https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4686-image-denoising-and-inpainting-with-deep-neural-networks.pdf

I have made the custom loss function they are using.

My set is a batch of overlapping patches (196x32x32) of an image. My input are the corrupted batches of the image, and the output should be the cleaned ones.

Part of my loss function is

```
dif_y = tf.subtract(y_xi,y_)

dif_norm = tf.norm(dif_y, ord = 'euclidean', axis = (1,2))
```

Where y_xi(196 x 1 x 3072) is the reconstructed clean image and y_ (196 x 1 x 3072) is the real clean image. So I actually I subtract all images from their corrupted version and I sum all those differences. I think it is normal to be a very big number.

```
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

The loss value begins at around 3*10^7 and is converging after 200 runs (I loop for 1000) at a close value. So my output image will be miles away from the original.

Edit: starts at 3.02391e+07 and converges to 3.02337e+07

Is there any way my loss value is correct? If so, how can I dramatically reduce it?

Thanks

Edit 2: My loss function

```
dif_y = tf.subtract(y,y_)
dif_norm = tf.norm(dif_y, ord = 'euclidean', axis = (1,2))
sqr_norm = tf.square(dif_norm)
prod = tf.multiply(sqr_norm,0.5)
sum_norm2 = tf.reduce_sum(prod,0)
error_1 = tf.divide(sum_norm2,196)
```

Comment: Such a high loss means the network is not able to fit your data/task, a different architecture (i.e deeper) could help.

Comment: can you provide the lines of code for your loss calculation.

Comment: @wontonimo I added the lines of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record if anyone else has a similar problem: Remember to normalize your data! I was actually subtracting values in range [0,1] from values in range [0,255]. Very noobish mistake, I learned it the hard way!

`Input values / 255`

`Expected values / 255`

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

**sum_norm2 = tf.reduce_sum(prod,0)** - I don't think this is doing what you want it to do.

Say **y** and **y_** have values for 500 images and you have 10 labels for a 500x10 matrix.  When **tf.reduce_sum(prod,0)** processes that you will have 1 value that is the sum of 500 values each which will be the sum of all values in the 2nd rank.

I don't think that is what you want, the sum of the error across each label.  Probably what you want is the average, at least in my experience that is what works wonders for me.  Additionally, I don't want a whole bunch of losses, one for each image, but instead one loss for the batch.

My preference is to use something like

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean ( tf.reduce_mean( prod ) )
```

This has the additional upshot of making your Optimizer parameters simple.  I haven't run into a situation yet where I have to use anything other than 1.0 for the learning_rate for GradientDescent, Adam, or MomentumOptimizer.

Now your loss will be independent of batch size or number of labels.

Comment: From my tests so far, I believe that the problem is the dif_norm = tf.norm(). Even when I run for a much smaller batch (15 images instead of 196) the loss stays the same (and value of the dif_norm). I agree with the idea that I want the loss to be for the whole batch instead of each image of the batch. Now, I take the average loss by dividing with the batch size(196) but I will definitely try it with  tf.reduce_mean. It makes sense. In addition do you believe I have to set my learning rate instead of leaving it up to Adam?

Comment: I'd start with using the default for Adam.  *Actually, I'd use Momentum first at least as a baseline. :)*

Comment: If someone reads the above comment about Momentum vs Adam and want's to learn more, here is a great link http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#gradientdescentoptimizationalgorithms which basically says, try Adam because it is awesome-er.